# Android Studio 3.1 layout unresponsive and freezing constantly

Tags: android, android-studio

Suddenly after the update to Android Studio 3.1, its UI becomes very unresponsive and slow. It feels like there are a bunch of jobs running on the UI thread. Does anyone see the same problem and is there a fix for it?

Comment: I think that you should wait when `android-studio` opens.. Because in the update of 3.1 minimum `target sdk` is increased. So it can be possible that your `android studio` is downloading its build-tools

Comment: Mine is working fine and smooth.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I had to downgrade it to 3.0.x

Answer (score 0):

My current solution to this issue is to downgrade Android Studio to 3.0.x. (Uninstall and reinstall 3.0.x package, and then ignore the 3.1 updates).

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on Windows 10 and OSX with Android 3.1.  It seems to be better now though.  This is what I did:
1) I bumped up the memory usage allowed in "Android Studio 3/bin/studio.exe.vmoptions" to:

```
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-da
```

2) I disabled inspections for c++ in Settings-->Editor-->Inspections